# Apply awk to everything except for first line

Tags: awk, sed

I'm looking to apply some awk processing to add the word "OR" to the beginning of each line, *except* for the first line. However, I'd still like the first line to print out.

Currently, I'm using the current command:

```
awk '$0="OR "$0' file.txt
```

This will give me the following output:

```
OR line1
OR line2
OR line3 etc
```

How can I get it so that it spits out the following?:

```
line1
OR line2
OR line3 etc
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this awk:

```sh
awk 'NR > 1 {$0 = "OR " $0} 1' file

line1
OR line2
OR line3
```

Here `NR > 1` condition will execute action block i.e. `$0 = "OR " $0` for 2nd record onwards only but `1` will print all the rows.

Comment: @CarlosPascual: It should be `awk 'NR>1 && index($0, "OR") != 1{$0 = "OR " $0} 1' file` of we want to check presence of `OR` at the line start

Comment: yes, you are right!! I remove the comment.

Answer (score 2):

`sed` solution

```
$ sed '2,$s/^/OR /' file
```

starting second line insert "OR " at the beginning of each line.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'NR==1 {print} NR>1 {print "OR "$0}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding one more approach here, written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '{print val $0; val="OR "}' Input_file
```

With shown samples, output will be as follows.

```
line1
OR line2
OR line3
OR line4
```

Answer (score 1):

Another awk

```
$ cat justin.dat
line1
line2
line3
line4
$ awk ' { printf("%s%s\n",sep,$0); sep="OR " } ' justin.dat
line1
OR line2
OR line3
OR line4
$
```